# How to compare td with td in previous row

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am trying to do is loop through each row of a table and compare the 1st cell of each row with the 1st cell of previous row. Seems like it should be simple and I am sure it is, but for now, I am lost with it..
Here is what I have.. I think I am close, but can't quite figure out what I have wrong.

```
$("tr td:first-child").each(function(){
    if(($(this).text()) == lastId){
    console.log("YEP, the same");
    }else{
    console.log("no, different Id");
     } 
     var lastId = $(this).text();
});
```

Comment: define `lastId` outside of the loop. As is, it's not defined at the comparison.

Comment: Declare `var lastId` outside the scope, before it is actually used.

Comment: It won't be defined for the first `td` either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep the variable lastId in another scope. Here it is lost on each iteration.

```
var lastId;
$("tr td:first-child").each(function(){
    if(($(this).text()) == lastId){
        console.log("YEP, the same");
    }else{
        console.log("no, different Id");
    } 
    lastId = $(this).text();
});
```

Comment: I don't know how I missed that... Thank you. I have been looking at this for an hour and just couldn't see what was happening.

Comment: Will accept your answer as soon as I can.. Just tried and said I had to wait 5 minutes.

Comment: By using a debugger in Firefox og Chrome you could find this easy.
Create a break point on the if statement and run it twise you would see that the variable lastId would be undefined. :)